# Connect two salesforce Personal Org

Tags: rest-api, force.com, webservices, rest

Can someone guide me how i can connect two salesforce personal Org using REST Services.

Basically I have very little idea about Web Services.

But i want to integrate two Org using REST web service.

Thanks in Advanvce Guys

Comment: Have you considered OOTB SF to SF feature? It helps for maintaining data sync between two orgs.

Comment: @salesforcemarty - I just got to know about SF -SF feature couple of minutes back